# missing:arm/abi system image for my android sdk 4.4w-20

Tags: android, sdk

I was trying to set up the environment to develop and debug a simple android app with the use of Android Virtual Device Manager.

I had followed all the steps from google's website.

Moving to the next step, as I had selected the target to be `Android 4.4W - API Level 20` details in the wizard `Create new android virtual device (AVD)`, the CPU/ABI field was grayed out saying "No system image installed for this target".

Can I download it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to open [Android SDK Manager](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html) which comes with your ADT Package that you downloaded.
You can download ARM/Intel x86 images for the API you want from there.

Comment: I am unable to do that, pls see my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25813579/948268