# How do I install System Images for Android 4.4W (API 20)

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android development. I am following the setup instructions on http://developer.android.com/ so I downloaded Eclipse ADT. While trying to create and Android Virtual Device (AVD) the OK button is disabled because I do not have System Images installed for the target (Android 4.4W - API Level 20). So I launched Android SDK Manager to download and install them, but I do not see any option to install them and also do not see "sources for android sdk" under "Android 4.4W (API20)". Here is snapshot of my the Android SDK Manager:

How to do I install System Images for Android 4.4W (API 20)

[image]

**EDIT:**
As suggested by @ashoke I installed Stand-alone SDK Tools but that too shows only this:
[image]

On launching the SDK Manager I am getting this exception:

```
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager] Exception in thread "Loading Sources" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: sun.net.PortConfig.getLower0()I
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.net.PortConfig.getLower0(Native Method)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.net.PortConfig.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.SocketPermission$1.run(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.SocketPermission.initEphemeralPorts(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.net.SocketPermission.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.util.SecurityConstants.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.Class.getProtectionDomain(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity$2.run(JceSecurity.java:226)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.JceSecurity.getCodeBase(JceSecurity.java:224)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.JceSecurityManager.getCryptoPermission(JceSecurityManager.java:107)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.Cipher.getConfiguredPermission(Cipher.java:2503)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.Cipher.initCryptoPermission(Cipher.java:685)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.Cipher.chooseProvider(Cipher.java:848)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1348)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherBox.newCipherBox(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.newCipher(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite$BulkCipher.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getApplicableCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl.getDefaultCipherSuiteList(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(Unknown Source)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:342)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openWithHttpClient(UrlOpener.java:404)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.UrlOpener.openUrl(UrlOpener.java:183)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:293)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:676)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:598)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetchXmlUrl(AddonsListFetcher.java:267)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.AddonsListFetcher.fetch(AddonsListFetcher.java:132)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsListInTask(PackageLoader.java:460)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.access$200(PackageLoader.java:47)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$3.run(PackageLoader.java:430)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:140)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView.startTask(ProgressView.java:162)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressViewFactory.start(ProgressViewFactory.java:46)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader.loadRemoteAddonsList(PackageLoader.java:427)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdklib.internal.repository.updater.PackageLoader$1.run(PackageLoader.java:233)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.tasks.ProgressView$2.run(ProgressView.java:130)
[2014-09-13 00:44:05 - SDK Manager] [SDK Manager]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check settings under tools, see if you enabled preview tools. My Android SDK Manager shows the system images for wear, please see below (also included my settings screenshot) :
[image: Android SDK Manager]

If it is still not working after you verified your settings, i would download the SDK tools only package http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and try with that.

Also try force https to http under options to get rid of exception in doing ssl.

Comment: I have `enabled preview tools` checked but still same behavior. Will try downloading SDK tools only package now, thanks.

Comment: I tried `SDK tools only`, could you pls suggest how to proceed with that.

Comment: point your eclipse IDE to new android SDK path. Since you already installed ADT, please follow configure section http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html and troubleshooting section if required.

Comment: I notice in your screenshot it is trying to fetch. Can you check your network connection...may be anti-virus or some-other software is blocking network connection. If you successfully installed SDK using this method, then follow my previous comment on how to proceed with eclipse. Also, under settings force http for https, it helps if there is an issue.

Comment: Disabled both firewall and antivirus. On launching SDK manager I am getting exception that I updated in the answer.

Comment: did you try force https to http under options, as i notice in that stack trace it is doing ssl. Close and reopen the SDK manager after changes to options.

Comment: yes, you are right. it now shows option to install System Images, I am doing that now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are running the internet on a proxy server so please specify the servers address and port address in 
Android SDK Manager>Tools>Proxy Settings
Enter the addresses
And you are good to go..